# Object Required despite already defining object (EXCEL, VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

**OBJECTIVE**

Pull in exchange rate data for various currencies.

**APPROACH**

1. Select Active Sheet and copy currencies-to-be-converted into an array (e.g ["EUR", "GBP", "USD"]
2. Open Browser and visit currency conversion website
3. Loop through different currencies and extract currency conversion factors
4. **Append conversion factors to an array**
5. **Repopulate excel with newest conversion factors**

**HTML**

```
<span class="amount" id="converterToAmount" style="">26.21</span>
```

**CODE**

```
Sub retreiveCurrencies()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim locals() As Variant
Dim rates As Object
Dim exchangeArray() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim IE As Object



'Select currencies to convert
Sheets("APPENDIX - CURRENCY CONVERTER").Activate
locals = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B15").Value
'This should return locals = ["EUR", "GBP, "USD"]

'Prep Internet Explorer
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True


'Loop through currencies and retreive rates. Paste rates into exchangeArray
For i = LBound(locals, 1) To UBound(locals, 1)
    IE.Navigate "http://www.usforex.com/currency-converter/" & locals(i, 1) & "/usd/1.00/false"
        Do While IE.Busy And Not IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
    '!!!!error on following line = "Object required"!!!!
    Set rates = IE.Document.GetElementById("converterToAmount").innerText
    ReDim Preserve exchangeArray(rates)

Next i

'Paste exchange rate array into currency conversion column
ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E15") = exchangeArray()



End Sub
```

**QUESTIONS/ISSUE(S)**

1. Currently getting error "Object Required" @ `Set rates = IE.Document.GetElementById("converterToAmount").innerText` despite defining `Dim rates As Object`. Any solution?
2. Is `ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E15") = exchangeArray()` sufficient to paste cells back into excel?

Comment: `rates` shouldn't be an object.  You're setting it to the value of the IE element's innertext, which is a string.  Try defining it as String and drop the `Set` keyword.

Comment: I could have sworn I had done this previously. Thank you for solving that issue. 

However, when I call 'MsgBox exchangeArray(i)' after the 'ReDim", I am not seeing any values. Am I misinterpreting something? For some reason, the rates are not being pulled and/or saved into the exchangeArray

Comment: I tend to define the target range with the extents of the variant array. e.g. `.Range("E2").Resize(UBound(exchangeArray, 1), UBound(exchangeArray, 2))  = exchangeArray`

Comment: If you are planning to put the values from `exchangeArray` back into the worksheet, it should be a two-dimensioned array, even if one of those dimensions is only `1 to 1`.

Comment: @Jeeped - I had to change "UBound(exchangeArray, 2)" to "UBound(exchangeArray, 1)" due to the error "Subscript out of Range". 

Do you mind if I ask why you prefer a two-dimensional array? 
Also, it appears that the values are not being properly recorded into the exchangeArray(rates) line

Comment: @kidlogic - When you write the array back to a Range, it needs to be a 2D array of Variant.

Comment: @Comintern - You can write a 1-D array back to the worksheet but for an `E2:E15` orientation, you would have to `[TRANSPOSE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027) it.

Comment: You are currently working with a 1-D array. Switch it for a 2-D array.

Comment: @Jeeped - Transpose returns a 2-D array.

Comment: @Comintern - `range("E1:G1") = array("1st col", "2nd col", "3rd col")` or `range("E1:E3") = application.transpose(array("1st row", "2nd row", "3rd row"))` . either works as a 1 D array passed back to the worksheet.

Comment: @Jeeped.  Huh - TIL.  I'm so used to working in 2 dimensions that I'd never even tried it.

Comment: @Comintern - I completely agree. It is just so much easier to work with apples and apples instead of oranges and apples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The title question was already addressed by @Dave in the comments - `.innerText` is a `String`, not an `Object`.

That said, your array syntax is a little off - `Redim Preserve` actually only resizes the array - it doesn't write a value to it.  You're also trying to use `rates` as the index instead of adding it.  Also, I'd take the suggestion @Jeeped makes in the comments and also apply it to your `exchangeArray`.  The size is fixed, and it will always be the same size as `locals`.  That means you can just do this:

```
ReDim exchangeArray(LBound(locals, 1) To UBound(locals, 1), LBound(locals, 2) To UBound(locals, 2))
```

Once it's already set to the correct size, you don't even have to `ReDim` it in the loop. Just mirror the position of your "key" array:

```
Dim rates As String
'...

'Loop through currencies and retreive rates. Paste rates into exchangeArray
ReDim exchangeArray(LBound(locals, 1) To UBound(locals, 1), LBound(locals, 2) To UBound(locals, 2))
For i = LBound(locals, 1) To UBound(locals, 1)
    ie.navigate "http://www.usforex.com/currency-converter/" & locals(i, 1) & "/usd/1.00/false"
        Do While ie.Busy And Not ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
    '!!!!error on following line = "Object required"!!!!
    rates = ie.document.getElementById("converterToAmount").innerText
    exchangeArray(i, 1) = rates
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you - this ties everything nicely together and illustrates where I went wrong. Marked as solution.